# Custom meta boxes in RSS feed

Tags: custom-field, rss

I've got a few custom meta fields I'd like to be displayed in RSS feeds. Right now they do not because they are not part of `the_content` I reckon.

If anyone has any tips for getting this to happen, please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, not tested,

```
add_filter('the_content_feed','add_my_fields_to_rss');

function add_my_fields_to_rss($content) {
  global $post;
  $mymeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta', true);
  $content .= $mymeta;
  return $content;
}
```